# How can I read the serial number directly from the broadcom chip instead of via /proc/cpuinfo?

Tags: hardware

There's numerous posts about reading the Pi's serial number from /proc/cpuinfo. I'm considering using the serial number as a unique id for licencing commercial software but am concercned that /proc/cpuinfo could possibly be faked (I stumbled on a few links that suggested it was easily possible but I haven't verified them: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=541842#p541842, [Editing Serial Number](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4385/editing-serial-number) etc.).

I also verify that /proc/cpuinfo reports a size of zero, but I'm not sure if that can also be worked around.

Is there a way to programmatically read the serial directly from the broadcom chip?

Comment: `using the serial number as a unique id ` FYI: the 'serial' number is not unique. They are randomly generated and people have seen the same ID come up already...

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @joan I'm using Raspbian Buster.

Comment: @Dirk - thanks for the head's up.

Comment: @Dirk - Do you happen to know if the serial is programmed by the raspberry pi foundation or the chip manufacturer (broadcom?)?

Comment: The number is programmed in the OTP register as part of the Pi production process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serial number is programmed into the [OTP register](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#otp-registers)

This can be read with `vcgencmd otp_dump`